# Grails:How to disable dates in calendar plugin

Tags: grails, groovy, calendar, datepicker, grails-plugin

I' have 2 text fields 1st one for giving date from and the other one for date to, what i want is while i'm selecting date from using 'calendar:datePicker' the dates before current date must be disabled and if i have selected a date 1/6/2014 in 1st text field, when i select the date to from the 2nd one the dates before 1/6/2014 must be disabled how can i achive this..?

```
From<calendar:datePicker name="datefrom"  years="${2014..2017}" value="${new Date()}" defaultValue="${new Date()}"/>


To<calendar:datePicker name="dateto"  years="${2014..2017}" value="${new Date()}" defaultValue="${new Date()}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks like an old plugin and it might not have the option that you need.

Use jQuery UI instead: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range

jQuery UI has a grails plugin as well. http://grails.org/plugin/jquery-ui